# writing error after running excel macro in python

Tags: python-2.7

I am a beginner in python scripts. Following simple writing gave me error message. Appreciate if someone can help me. Thank you.

```
prob_per1 = 1.5
myfile = open('probability.txt','w') 
myfile.write(prob_per1)
myfile.close()
```

error message in Visual Studio
[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

You try to write `float` in file, but method `.write` [doesn't take arguments in non-string format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=file.write#file.write), try to write it with convert in `string` like this:

`myfile.write( str ( prob_per1 ) )`